# Url passed on has Escaped Characters. Htaccess rule to correct

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, html-escape-characters

I need advise for htaccess rule to decode url string for instance:

Actual Page is

```
http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_latestnews&view=detail&n_id=953&Itemid=10
```

But Page is cached in Google as

```
http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_latestnews%26view%3Ddetail%26n_id%3D953%26Itemid%3D10
```

Decoded string will lead to correct url

I am sorry as is not at all aware of htaccess rule, hence not pasting code. Is there any htaccess rule to remove escaped characters and lead to correct url through redirect

Update
Like as given in
   https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Basic_backend

```html
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
 
// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
 
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JController::getInstance('HelloWorld');
 
// Get the task
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$task = $jinput->get('task', "", 'STR' );

 
// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute($task);
 
// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

Shall i add this line in get the task - will it do the needful

```
   $url = urldecode($jinput->get('url', '', 'string'));
```

Final Code is

```html
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'pager.cls.php' );
 
// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
 
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JController::getInstance('HelloWorld');
 
// Get the task
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$task = urldecode($jinput->get('task', "", 'STR' ));
 
// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute($task);
 
// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();

?>
```

HTACCESS COde - Though working Good Partially but is notconverting %3f to ?

```html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1\%3F%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE]
```

Update - Final HTACCESS

```html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks - and how to decode same in php

Comment: [You can use urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: @anubhava - Edit done, Can you advise is this the correct way to add urldecode as given in sample code

Comment: Thanks - but somehow - still looks like an issue and primarily due to %3F - Is it possible through htaccess to decode %3f to ? mark - It may likely serve in purpose

Comment: Htaccess code is appended - though working partially - but not converting %3f to ?

Comment: @anubhava - Have got this rule - it works - but unsure - does it pose any security concern or any other issue - Pls advise RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE]

Comment: In my PHP code `echo urldecode('http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_latestnews%26view%3Ddetail%26n_id%3D953%26Itemid%3D10');` is correctly giving `http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_latestnews&view=detail&n_id=953&Itemid=10` ad there was no need of any rule.

Comment: But sir - above is just an example - there are many other urls which are occurring like this. Wont htaccess code serve the purpose. Is there any flaw in htaccess rule

Comment: I have no idea what is it doing and `urldecode` is sufficient for decoding.